# Is there any other God other than the one true God of Jesus Christ, John 17:3?

Tags: john

Is there any other God greater than the one true God of Jesus Christ whom he said is greater than all, including Jesus Christ, John 10:29 and John 14:28?

Comment: No there is none greater than God.  But that God includes the Father Son and Holy Spirit.  Keep plugging away at it Alex!

Comment: @Dottard He's right you know.   "You, the only true God" is a convertible proposition.

Comment: I wish that you and @ThomasPearne would stop using this site to try to gain converts.

Comment: @Dottard According to Wallace it is.  Nouns in simple apposition have an understood to-be verb.

Comment: … and your point is?  The act of you asserting via an obscure reference that this is a convertible proposition proves nothing.  It remains a proposition not an argument nor reason

Comment: @Dottard  Here:  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/47212/33125

Comment: Correct - and see my answer there!

Answer (score 5):

In the Bible, the greatest teaching is expressed in the Shema:

> שְׁמַ֖ע יִשְׂרָאֵ֑ל יְהוָ֥ה אֱלֹהֵ֖ינוּ יְהוָ֥ה ׀ אֶחָֽד
>
> Hear, O Israel: The LORD our God, the LORD is one.

This is repeated in numerous other places:

- Deut 4:35, You were shown these things so that you would know that the LORD is God; there is no other besides Him.
- Isa 44:6, "This is what the LORD says-- Israel's King and Redeemer, the LORD Almighty: I am the first and I am the last; apart from me there is no God."
- Isa 45:5, 6, “I am the LORD, and there is no other; Besides Me there is no God.  I will gird you, though you have not known Me; That men may know from the rising to the setting of the sun, That there is no one besides Me.  I am the LORD, and there is no other.
- 1 Cor 8:4, There is no God but one.
- 1 Tim 1:17, Now to the King eternal, immortal, invisible, the only God, be honor and glory for ever and ever.

Let there be no doubt that the Bible is stridently monotheistic; no ifs, no buts about it.

This one God is the God we must know to the extent that we can know Him.  In the Old Testament, God is referred to in many places as more than one person such as:

- Zech 2:6-12 – the LORD (= YHWH) claims three times that He has been sent by the LORD.
- Isa 48:11-16 – again, the LORD has been sent by the LORD.
- Isa 63:7-10 – the LORD (described as a Father) sends His divine servant (the angel of His presence) and His Holy Spirit who is grieved (compare Ps 78:40).
- Ex 23:20 – the angel of the LORD’s presence has the power to forgive sin (but will not).  This and the previous reference clearly make the angel of the presence is the pre-incarnate Jesus.
- Hos 1:7 – the LORD saves by the LORD their God.
- Prov 30:1-4 – the Son of God is as unfathomable as God Himself.
- Psalm 110 – “The LORD says to my Lord” – Jesus asked about this Psalm on how someone could be both Son and Lord of David – see Matt 22:44, Mark 12:36, Luke 20:42, Acts 2:34.
- Ps 45 (quoted by Heb 1) talks about the “Son” being God in addition to God the Father (v6-8).

Thus, there is but one God.  Note that God is Love (1 John 4:8, 16) and because God is eternal, God has always been love.  Note this carefully:  A single person cannot be ἀγάπη (agapē) love because this is primarily outwardly focused.  For God to be ἀγάπη (agapē) love, God must be a mutuality of more than one person, else this statement has no meaning.

The NT clearly portrays this one God as a mutuality of three people Matt 3:16, 17, 12:28, 28:19, Mark 1:10,11, Luke 3:21, 22, John 1:32, 14:26, 15:26-16:14, Acts 2:33, 10:38, Rom 1:2-4, 8:9, 15:30, 1 Cor 6:11, 12:2-6, 2 Cor 13:14, Gal 3:11-14, 4:6, Eph 1:17, 2:18, 22, Titus 3:6, Heb 9:14, 10:29, 1 Peter 1:2, 3, 3:18, 4:14, Jude 20, 21.

**CONCLUSION**

There is no other God, but the one true God, and that one true God consists of three persons.

Comment: The trinity is never mentioned in the bible and Jesus never mentions he is God.  Nothing in the bible can justify the trinity.  Even the only verse 1 john 5:7 that mentions 3, was removed from the RSV as a fabrication. John 14:28 “You heard me say, ‘I am going away and I am coming back to you.’ If you loved me, you would be glad that I am going to the Father, for the Father is greater than I (not equal or same). John 5:30 ‘cannot to anything myself. John 10:29 & 14:16, Matthew 12:28, Luke 11:20 and so much more I could go on and on - no evidence in bible.

Comment: You have not read my list of texts above such as Matt 28:19, 2 Cor 13:14, etc.  The fact that the Trinity is not explicit does not make it untrue.  Monogamy is never mentioned either.  Antislavery is never mentioned, religious freedom is never mentioned, etc.

Comment: I did read your text it doesn’t advance your point, nothing proves 3=1 including Matt 28:19 - Shem Tob’s (or Shem Tov) Hebrew Gospel of Matthew which is translated from Hebrew to English by George Howard - Matt 28:19-20 go and (teach) them to carry out all things which I have commanded you forever.  What you have quoted was not in the original early manuscripts.

Eusebuis quotes:  “Go ye, and make disciples of all the nations, teaching them to observe all things, whatsoever I have commanded you.”  Considerable information on the web

Comment: even than Matt 28:19 if correct doesn’t prove 3=1 3 different and   Matthew 28:18 Then Jesus came to them and said,“All authority in heaven and on earth has been given to me. This contradicts (19) if Jesus is God why does he need authority to be given to him? the point you make if it’s not mentioned doesn’t make it untrue, basically you can believe whatever you want.

Comment: @anothertheory Trinitarians do not believe that 3 = 1. They especially do not believe that the Father = the Son = the Spirit.

Comment: In every good marriage, there are two people that speak with one voice.  However, no one suggests that 2 = 1.  There are two people but one marriage.  There is one God and three persons

Comment: @curiousdannii you can put it ‘one God in three Divine persons’ etc in my opinion it amounts to the same, agree or not agree.  In any event no evidence in the bible that I have ever been show, more than welcome to prove me wrong with any evidence.

Comment: @anothertheory No, it's a huge difference. It's the difference between saying 1 = 3 and saying one respiratory system and two lungs. You need to recognise that what is counted as 1 and what is counted as 3 are not in the same category.

Comment: @curiousdannii I respect that this is how you want to see it and that’s fine.  To me trinity is illogical with no evidence.

Comment: Some insist that trinity is in the bible though it clearly is not and some have removed the YHWH from the bible when it clearly is there, mentioned almost 7000 times, more than any other name in the scripture.

Comment: Math does not lie. 1+1+1  = 3

Comment: @AlexBalilo - Again, that is not what Trinitarians teach.  At least try to understand a doctrine before criticising, please.